# adding handler to button code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am rendering some html in code behind using StringBuilder which includes a button. I am also  trying to add a handler to this and I think perhaps not surprisingly it does not fire. Can I include an event handler to a button in this way?

```
sb.Append("<td>");
sb.Append("<input type='button' runat='server' id='butResetPassword' value='Reset Password' onserverclick='butSendEmail_Click' />");
sb.Append("</td>");
User.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

this is the eventhandler that appears in the same code behind page

```
protected void butSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labTester.InnerText = "Thanks for clicking me";

 }
```

Comment: You are rendering <input type='button' runat='server' id='butResetPassword' value='Reset Password' onserverclick='butSendEmail_Click' /> on client side, this doesn't make sense. onserverclick on client side will not do the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question of yours recently.

Unless you have a really good reason to generate markup in the code behind, keep it separate, otherwise stick to classic ASP.

You can do:

Markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="butResetPassword" OnClick="butSendEmail_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void butSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Reset the password here
    labTester.InnerText = "Thanks for clicking me";
}
```

Edit* If all you need to do is display that confirmation message and not interact with any data or controls, then you could bind the button to a js function, change `onserverclick` to `onclick`:

```
<input type='button' runat='server' id='butResetPassword' value='Reset Password' onclick='butSendEmail_Click' />
```

And then have some js to handle this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function butSendEmail_Click() {
       alert("Thanks for clicking me");

       //Or set the labels text
       var elem = document.getElementById("labTester");
       elem.InnerHtml = "Thanks for clicking me";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Will avoid that. Thanks. Will use the DataList instead